# MVC4 : Save as html and email it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I know i am asking for information here but seems like a relevant question and i am getting no ideas how to do it . please help.

Problem: We have requirements to send an email with a html attachment.

Sending E-mail part is taken care of as a part of our APT but the problem is with the html attachment.

Requirement: we have to send the current view which is displayed on the UI as a html file.

How can i get the full html in the controller from the view?

```
  Attachment = new AttachmentContract
            {
                Path = AppSettings.NoticeAttachmentFilePath,
                FileName = "filenamehtml",
                Content = <<here we want to set that html>>
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps integrating the RazorEngine could help you out: http://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution guys with the help of some other question here's what i am doing

```
 Attachment = new AttachmentContract
        {
            Path = AppSettings.NoticeAttachmentFilePath,
            FileName = "filenamehtml",
            Content = testmethod()
        }

 private string TestMethod(ModelData modelData)
    {

        ViewData.Model = modelData;
        StringWriter output;
        using (output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(this.ControllerContext, "EmailAttachment", null);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, result.View, this.ViewData, this.ControllerContext.Controller.TempData, output);
            result.View.Render(viewContext, output);
            result.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(this.ControllerContext, result.View);
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }

Where EmailAttachment is a view i am going to fill in my logic using the same model
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like this:

https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer

Comment: we already have our API for sending down e-mails. So was looking for just a MVC way to get the current view as html in the controller so we can set the content as i have mentioned above