# Get the Current page html and set a hidden field (MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to capture the Current page Html and was wondering to see how can i set a hiddenfield using the razor syntax

Filed i want to set

```
@Html.Hidden("pageHtml")
```

i am currently using javascript to get the page html but the same thing i want to try using @Html attribute or something

```
var html1 = $('#wrapper').html();
var encodedString = escape(html1);
$('#pageHtml').val(encodedString);
```

or if someone can help me finding a way to get the current view html in the controller action

Please make some suggestions

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you're trying to do? If you want to edit the value of an element from the controller.. make it a model property and use `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Property)`...

Comment: I need the html of the page to create a full e-mail attachment. The problem is how i will set the modal property.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.. Please edit it in order to explain better what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this is how we are doing it finally...(our page does not contain any secure data so we have gone for this)

- Added a hidden field to hold the html
- Use the javascript method to set the hidden field with the encoded page html
    var html1 = $('#wrapper').html();
    var encodedString = escape(html1);
- Changed the controller to take the hidden field as a parameter. (to pass the encoded html)
- Unescaped the html using

  var html = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(pageHtml);

Answer (score 4):

First, create a Controller Extension method `ViewToString` as below:
This will extend System.Web.Mvc.Controller to have a new method called `ViewToString` and it will  render Your views HTML into a StringReader

```
namespace YourProject.ControllerExtensions
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    public static class ControllerExtend
    {
        public static StringReader ViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
        {
            #region MyRegion
            ControllerContext context = controller.ControllerContext;
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }
            if (model != null)
            {
                controller.ViewData.Model = model;
            }
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {                
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(context, viewResult.View);


                //return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
                return new StringReader(sw.ToString());

            }
            #endregion
        }


    }
}
```

Now, call the above method in your Controller Action to access to your Views HTML and pass `Your View Name` and `Your Model Name` ( If you have no model, pass null):

```
public ActionResult YourControllerAction()
{

    //....      
    StringReader htmlView = this.ViewToString("YourViewName", YourModelObject);    
    //Now htmlView containing the HTML of Your View 
    //and you can pass it to your Email function .....
// ...

}
```

htmlView will contain the HTML from Your view ...

Hope this would of some help ...

Comment: A good answer to a very unclear question! :) Only a doubt: why a StringReader? Why not a String?

Comment: Thanks Maddy. we were doing the same thing (see the question answered by me) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128137/mvc4-save-as-html-and-email-it but just wanted to see if there is a straight forward way of doing this.

Comment: @LorenzoDematté mentioning question is unclear in every comment is not going to help me or anyone. my question was very simple hence no big details was provided.

Comment: @fireholster actually, making your question clear will help you in getting a better answer. Also, it will benefit other people that will come after you looking for a similar problem. Simply editing the question to include your first comment would already be a great improvement!

Comment: Well, The output of the ViewToString can be String, StringReader or StringBuilder depends on how you are going to consume. I was going to stream the output and create a PDF from the HTML and StringBulder and StringReader were a better options for me. Generally if there is going to be many string manipulation, StringBuilder is a better choice.

Comment: @fireholster I found this way more secure with a better performance to compare to having your pages HTML as a hidden field to send to  server to be used in an action method. it also reduce the data transfer between User's browser and MVC Action on the Server..

Comment: @Maddy true..though i was having the escaped version of the html..so it was pretty much garbled..but you are right if i go with the above method it will definitely reduce the crap on the browser.